# Pivot SQL table with Text columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a simple table in SQL server like this below.

```
CREATE TABLE chemical(
    [chemical] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [region] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [asset] [varchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO chemical ([chemical],[region],[asset])     VALUES ('a','region1','asset1')
INSERT INTO chemical ([chemical],[region],[asset])     VALUES ('a','region2','asset1')
INSERT INTO chemical ([chemical],[region],[asset])     VALUES ('a','region1','asset2')
```

Data will look like this:

| chemical | Region | Asset |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | region1 | asset1 |
| a | region2 | asset1 |
| a | region1 | asset2 |

I would like to PIVOT the information as:

| Chemical | Info |
| --- | --- |
| a | region1_asset1, region1_asset2, region2_asset1 |

I tried using the PIVOT functionality but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (SQL Server perhaps? Which version?)

Comment: To follow from @jarlh [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: SQL Server. Added the tag. Thanks

Comment: For SQL Server, take a look at STRING_AGG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally a good use case for `STRING_AGG`, see this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) about that function.

We just need to take care of some important things to make sure the result will be as intended:

- Although your sample data contains data for one single chemical only, we will certainly need a `GROUP BY` clause to still get the correct result when further chemicals appear in the table.
- We need to put together the columns "region" and "asset" with an underscore between them. We can use `CONCAT` for that.
- We need to use an `ORDER BY` clause (at least according to your sample data, otherwise ignore this point) within the `STRING_AGG`.

So the entire query will be this one:

```
SELECT
  chemical, 
  STRING_AGG(CONCAT(region,'_',asset),', ') 
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY region) AS Info
FROM chemical
  GROUP BY chemical
  ORDER BY chemical;
```

See this [fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/5BL52JTa) based on your sample data, but with some further chemicals that show why to add the `GROUP BY` clause.

To show the difference caused by the `ORDER BY region` part of above query:

This result...

```
region1_asset2, region1_asset1, region2_asset1
```

...would be this one without ordering:

```
region1_asset1, region2_asset1, region1_asset2
```

That's also shown in the fiddle.